# Implementation of count() in Boost's dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset

I'm profiling some code which uses a `dynamic_bitset<>` and I've found my bottleneck occurs in the `count()` function, which needs to be called millions of times in a for loop.  To be brief, the for loop takes pairs of bitsets, calculates the set intersection using `&`, and then saves the Hamming weight using `count()`.

To compare to the regular `<bitset>` in STL, I implemented a bitset as an array of long's and used the `__builtin_popcountl()` (used in `<bitset>`), and found it was much slower - about 50% slower.  Has anyone looked at boost's `do_count()` function, found in `<boost/detail/dynamic_bitset.hpp>`, because it uses some lookup table which I don't understand at all.

To be more clear, my question is why Boost's `do_count()` is so much more efficient than `__builtin_popcount()`?

Comment: I can't understand what the question is here, can you elaborate?

Comment: Hard to say, without knowing what Boost version and, more importantly, which C++ compiler and version you're using. And then you could of course just compare the implementations yourself…

Comment: I'm using g++ 4.7.3 and boost 1.55.0.  Here's a twist - I simply "borrowed" the function defined in Boost, and my implementation is twice the speed Boost's is.  The only difference I can tell is Boost is using iterators while I use raw arrays.

Comment: Also, what architecture have you benchmarked this on? What were your optimization settings?

Comment: Centos 6.7 64-bit, optimized with the -O3 flag.  Running on a Xeon E5-2680v3.

Comment: If your CPU doesn't have __builtin_popcount, compiler substitutes it with regular for loop. Although most modern CPUs have __builtin_popcount, maybe your CPU doesn't?